# Android FileObserver battery drain

Tags: android, fileobserver

I'm implementing a file observer in the main activity of a home replacement app. 
Does it drain battery?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't done any testing, but I would tend to guess the effect would be fairly minimal.  The mechanism is built into the kernel so assuming you use a blocking call it's fairly lightweight and only consumes userspace cycles when the condition is met, plus a few kernel ones on every access to check if it qualifies.  And there doesn't seem to be much reason to hold a wakelock for this, since a file can't really be modified when the processor isn't already running...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileObserver should not drain battery.

FileObserver listens for iNotify events, which are implemented as core functionality via the Linux kernel.

Just initialize your FileObserver with the events you want to listen to and implement the onEvent callback: it should be okay.