# Best way to invoke an action when photo or video is taken?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I want to trigger an Asynctask whenever a photo or video is captured, but none of the intents below seem to be fired when I take a photo using the stock camera app on my Galaxy S4:

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
        <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

So my question is: would it be more reliable to trigger my Asynctask whenever a file is added to a designated folder? (e.g. the DCIM/camera folder)? If so, how can that be done?

Comment: you want to run your asyntask during capturing  or after capture video/photos ?

Comment: I want to run if after the capture of videos/photos

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it using this

```
FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA") { // set up a file observer to watch the DCIM directory
            @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
            if(event == FileObserver.CREATE && !file.equals(".probe")){ // check if its a "create" and not equal to .probe because thats created every time camera is started
                Log.d(TAG, "File created [" + android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/" + file + "]");
                fileSaved = "New photo Saved: " + file;

//You could do other stuff here

            }
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
```

But if for some other reason the pictures are not getting saved in the DCIM folder you can set a fileobserver on all folders like this

```
FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks good. If you wanted this running in the background the whole time where would be the best place to put this code?

Comment: To run a code in the background i think you should use services. here is a link of an implementation of a service https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services or you could check out the docs on services

Comment: Thanks.Thinking about,it, maybe a FileObserver that runs all the time is a bit of a no-no from a resource usage and battery drain point of view. Would that be fair to say?

Comment: Fileobserver shouldn't drain the battery....at least this post says so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223155/android-fileobserver-battery-drain

Comment: While Fileobserver itself may not drain the battery, presumably it would need to be initiated within a permanently-running service of the app, which would itself be a drain on resources?